# Mysql Procedure Get Data From Temporary Table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have create mysql store procedure created a temporary table on it.Now i want to fetch all the data from temp table.How can i do this?Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Call your_sp_name; /* so data could insert into temp table*/

SELECT * FROM temp_table_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick replay.But you are not getting my point

I have created a temp table 'Category_List' using below procedure. Now i want to do something like that in my procedure not in the php code

foreach(Category_List as $v)
{
 insert into abc values(category)
}


CREATE  TEMPORARY table Category_List SELECT smatrix.category 
from xyz as smatrix 
where 
smatrix.Gender = x 
and 
smatrix.DressCode = y;